# Replace everything except ONE single char

Tags: java, regex, string

I am dealing with some cells where I have to extract certain letters from these cells. I want to replace a whole String with " " except from one single-standing character. The biggest challenge to me has been to tell my Regex code only to look for a single Char and remove everything else.
To further elaborate and simplify; I need my Regex to replace everything with "" execept from a single character that standa ALONE (I.E white spaces left and right or linked to a number)

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "22A 302 abc";
        String works = test.replaceAll("^\\w[\\s\\S]*", " ");
        System.out.println(works);
        //Desired result: A
    }
}
```

Comment: Try it like this `^[^A-Z]*((?<=[ \d])[A-Z])(?=[ \d])[^A-Z]*$` https://regex101.com/r/mGKwkb/1 and replace with group 1. Or match it instead of lookarounds `^.*[\d ]([A-Z])[ \d].*$` https://regex101.com/r/oas6PP/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird  I tried it. Does not replace it the way I asked when I run it

Comment: You have to double escape the backslash in Java. Let me add the demo code.

Comment: I have added the updated code to the answer.

Comment: @Thefourthbird We have an issue. It does not replace as intented when there is a comma for example "22A, 02 abc" - It keeps the values like this. Same goes for dots and other special characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could match a digit or space before and after capturing a char `[A-Z]`.

In the replacement use group 1.

```
^.*[\d ]([A-Z])[ \d].*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zka1xw/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/lGF5iS)

If there can be only a single uppercase char in the string:

```
^[^A-Z]*[\d ]([A-Z])[ \d][^A-Z]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VKpSYS/1)

Example code

```
String test = "22A 302 abc";
String works = test.replaceAll("^.*[\\d ]([A-Z])[ \\d].*$", "$1");
System.out.println(works);
```

Output

```
A
```

---

To match between digits 0-9, horizontal whitespace chars or punctuations:

```
String works = test.replaceAll("^.*[\\p{P}0-9\\h]([A-Z])[\\p{P}0-9\\h].*$", "$1");
```

Comment: @WallyAden So on the left and right should be either a space, digit or a `.` or `,`

Comment: Yup - Seems like this is what it lacks to fully function

Comment: You can list in the character class what you would allow `^.*[\d .,]([A-Z])[\d .,].*$` https://regex101.com/r/7R4Uu5/1

Comment: @WallyAden If you want to match all punctuations, digits and horizontal whitespace chars, you could also use `String regex = "^.*[\\p{P}0-9\\h]([A-Z])[\\p{P}0-9\\h].*$";`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "22A 302 abc";
        String works = test.replaceAll("\\d+([A-Z]).*", "$1");
        System.out.println(works);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
A
```

**Explanation:** Replace everything with capturing group-1 (`$1` in the code given above) which has just a letter `A-Z` preceded by an integer number(`\\d+`) and can have anything (`.*`) after it.